# JQuery toggle on hidden div not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to toggle visibility of certain div on click of button. My HTML looks like follow

```
<div id="button">
    <button> button </button>
</div>
<div id="somedata" class="hidden">
    <label> some data</label>
</div>
```

Corresponding JQuery code is

```
$("#button").click( function() {
     $("#somedata").removeClass("hidden");
     $("#somedata").fadeToggle("slide");
});
```

This works perfectly except for the first time you click the button. 
When you click on the button first time, it just appears and dis-appears immediately.

I really need to make that div hidden by default.

Check this link for demo : 
[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w48s5cfy/)

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Ganesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start as `hidden` : swap 2 lines

```
$("#somedata").removeClass("hidden");
$("#somedata").fadeToggle("slide");
```

To

```
$("#somedata").fadeToggle("slide");
$("#somedata").removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: Then it will start visible.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question **I really need to make that div hidden by default.**

Comment: Well, that helps!
Thank you very much. 
Can you explain what the code means?

Comment: @GaneshS, well, firstly your code make text visible by removing class hidden, but jquery function `fadetoggle` again make text invisible by adding inline css `display:none`. After this `fadetoggle` just works with inline css, so behaviour was as you expected.

Answer (score 6):

The `hidden` class in Bootstrap includes `visibility: hidden` which is what is causing the issue. Set the element to `display: none` only and it works:

```
#somedata {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#somedata").fadeToggle("slide");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/w48s5cfy/1/)

Comment: Thing is I can't edit the CSS :(. Is there anyway I can do it with HTML or JS??

Comment: I could not figure out why toggle() would not change the visibility of an element. You included 'display:none';problem solved. TY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .toggle() function and it will get the job done.

```
<div id="button">
    <button> button </button>
</div>
<div id="somedata">
    <label> some data</label>
</div>

<script>
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $("#somedata").toggle(500); //animation in milliseconds
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `toggle()` does not animate though.

Comment: toggle, fadeToggle, slideToggle does not make any difference

Comment: try $("#somedata").toggle(500); //enter milliseconds as parameter